# How to clarify function of save button? 'Save and close' vs 'Save and exit'

Tags: buttons, save

What is the most clear way of saying that the save button will also close a window/action/process?

I have a web application with a launch page with several links. When the user enters a single application from one of the links, there is an option to create an element. When the user starts the creating process, he is sent to another page (launch page > application > create).

The problem is with the save/finish button. Right now the button just says "Save". But to me it looks like the save button in Word or any other application where you just save and then keep working or you have to click on a second button to close it.

And to user "Save and exit" makes it sound like the user will be sent back to the launch page, doesn't it?

How do I clarify what the button actually does, i.e. saves and sends the user back to the application)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've come across the same situation in a project I'm working on and I went for the 'save and close' option because it's an active description of what will happen when the user clicks on the button. This is not based on any research. It's just a preference.

Answer (score 2):

How about "**Done**"?

[image]

It implies that there's nothing left to do and will leave it with the changes intact.

Answer (score 2):

**Just say exactly what the button does**

Part of the problem here is that you seem to have the invisible constraint that you should have just one word per action - 'Save & X'

If the button saves and returns the user to the application, then make the CTA

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fArI1t.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>